# Acess files on root in device

Tags: android, filesystems

I'm developing an application for Galaxy Tab, and now I need get some files on the /data/data// folder.

The emulator is really, really slow. So I'm testing on device, and need get the files from device (from emulator i'm able to do). How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a debug function in your code to copy the required files from the protected folders onto your phone's SD card.  You can then access them from your PC.

```
public static void backupFile() throws IOException {

  String inFileName = "/data/data/your.package.name/........"; //TODO Use folder/filename
  File inFile = new File(inFileName);
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inFile);

  String outFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/........"; //TODO Use output filename
  OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int length;
  while ((length = fis.read(buffer))>0)
    output.write(buffer, 0, length);

  output.flush();
  output.close();
  fis.close();
}
```

Comment: Ah, Nifty!  This will come in handy.

Comment: Interisting. I think this can be an solution.

Answer (score 3):

The /data directory on a device has restricted permissions.  To copy files off using adb you will need to have rooted your device.

Answer (score 1):

```
adb pull <path>
```

will download files from the device to your current directory.

You can also use `adb shell` to explore your device using common shell commands. `adb shell ls <path>` will let you do this without actually entering the shell completely.

**Edit** - this will not work for files in the /data directory or other restricted directories unless you have root access to the device.

Comment: yes, unfortunately certain directories are restricted. Your application directory in /data/data shouldn't be.

Comment: interesting.  I was under the impression that nothing under /data/data would be accessible this way.  I've never been able to pull any files from /data on an unrooted device.  Perhaps I've just never picked the right files?

Comment: hmm, I guess you're right! I could've sworn that I've done this before. It must've just been on the emulator.

Comment: Well, thanks for double checking!  I was really hoping I was wrong :-)