# unable to access file on android

Tags: android, file, root, android-file

**EDIT:** An error is occurring when i tried to implement the suggested solutions. Please view the additional information below. Please assist me if you can, thanks in advance!

Ok, so i finally got my application to create and write to a file recently.

On the emulator this works perfectly. However, when i upload the application to my phone and try `adb shell` into my phone. I am unable to get to the directory on my phone that contains the file.

The directory is `/data/data/cpe495.smartapp/files/`. When i try to change directory it tells me that i do not have permission.

I am assuming this is because i do not have my phone rooted and am not in the root account. Rooting my phone is not something i am going to do.

Is there a way that i can create this file and write to it and be able to `adb pull` it off of my phone? Here is the current way i am creating the file:

```
fOut = tThis.openFileOutput("test.csv", tThis.MODE_APPEND);
```

Thanks in advance!!

**Still Not Working**

I have added the following code to me application and when i run it and when it tries to write the file to the sdcard it fails with the following error, please assist me!

```
                      String inFileName = "/data/data/cpe495.smartapp/files/test.csv"; //TODO Use folder/filename
                      File inFile = new File(inFileName);
                      try{
                      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inFile);

                      String outFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test.csv"; //TODO Use output filename
                      OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

                      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                      int length;
                      while ((length = fis.read(buffer))>0)
                        output.write(buffer, 0, length);

                      output.flush();
                      output.close();
                      fis.close();
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
```

---

```
04-05 23:20:11.551: WARN/System.err(285): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/test.csv (Permission denied)
04-05 23:20:11.582: WARN/System.err(285):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.openImpl(Native Method)
04-05 23:20:11.593: WARN/System.err(285):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:152)
04-05 23:20:11.601: WARN/System.err(285):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:97)
04-05 23:20:11.601: WARN/System.err(285):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:168)
04-05 23:20:11.612: WARN/System.err(285):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:147)
04-05 23:20:11.622: WARN/System.err(285):     at cpe495.smartapp.SmartApp$8.onClick(SmartApp.java:162)
04-05 23:20:11.622: WARN/System.err(285):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-05 23:20:11.632: WARN/System.err(285):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-05 23:20:11.632: WARN/System.err(285):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-05 23:20:11.642: WARN/System.err(285):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-05 23:20:11.642: WARN/System.err(285):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-05 23:20:11.685: WARN/System.err(285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-05 23:20:11.685: WARN/System.err(285):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 23:20:11.692: WARN/System.err(285):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-05 23:20:11.702: WARN/System.err(285):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-05 23:20:11.702: WARN/System.err(285):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-05 23:20:11.711: WARN/System.err(285):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I asked about getting files into root http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434100/acess-files-on-root-in-device

Comment: When i tried your code it gave me the following error. Please see my op for additional information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right about needing root access to access that file.

As a workaround, you can create an activity or test function that copies that file to the SD card so that you can read it.

**Edit** - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434100/acess-files-on-root-in-device/5434965#5434965) contains sample code for copying a file to the SD card.

**Update** - for the above answer you will need in your manifest after the `<manifest ... >` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Have any tips or suggestions on how to do that? I tried writing to the sd card earlier and it would not work on the emulator.

Comment: Yeah, the comment made by Marcos pointed me to that answer. I am testing that implementation at the moment.

Comment: I tried the code you posted as an example and it is not working, tells me permission is denied. Please see my op for additional information.

Comment: Do you have the external storage write permission in your manifest?

Comment: Yes i do, and it is not working. However, i am testing this on the emulator before the real thing. Someone somewhere else mentioned that i may need to add an sd card to the device on the emulator, do i need to do this?

Comment: Yes, you'd definitely need an SD card attached.

Comment: Have you done this before? If so, do you know a good tutorial?

Comment: I haven't used that specific code before. Maybe you can post your logcat output?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that question. I figured out how to add the sdcard. It was fairly easy.